# Spring-Data-JPA with QueryDslPredicateExecutor and Joining into a collection

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Let's say I have a data model like this (pseudocode):

```
@Entity
Person {
    @OneToMany
    List<PersonAttribute> attributes;
}

@Entity
PersonAttribute {
    @ManyToOne
    AttributeName attributeName;

    String attributeValue;
}

@Entity
AttributeName {
    String name;
}
```

I have a Spring-Data-JPA repository defined such as:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Person>{}
```

I see in the QueryDSL documentation that there is a mechanism to Join from the Person to the  PersonAttribute, but it looks like you need access to the QueryDsl Query object, which the client of the repository wouldn't have.

What I would like to do with my Predicate is to find all those Persons that have an AttributeValue (there's one join) with a value of "blue" and an AttributeName (there's another join) with a name of "eyecolor".  I'm not sure how I would do that with an `any()` and enforce that I only get those with eye_color=blue and not those with shoe_color=blue.

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
QPerson person = QPerson.person;
QPersonAttribute attribute = person.attributes.any();

Predicate predicate = person.name.toLowerCase().startsWith("jo")
    .and(attribute.attributeName().name.toLowerCase().eq("eye color")
          .and(attribute.attributeValue.toLowerCase().eq("blue")));
```

but with the `any()` in there it just matches anything with an attribute value of "blue" and anything with an "eye color" attribute regardless of color.  **How I can make those conditions apply to the same attribute within the set?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't directly join a column in a predicate but you can create an any() expressions like this

```
QPerson.person.attributes.any().attributeValue.eq("X")
```

This approach has the restriction that the join expression `QPerson.person.attributes.any()` can be used in only one filter. It has though the benefit that this expression is internally converted into a subquery which doesn't conflict with paging.

For multiple restrictions you will need to construct a subquery expression explicitly like this

```
QPersonAttribute attribute = QPersonAttribute.personAttribute;
new JPASubQuery().from(attribute)
    .where(attribute.in(person.attributes),
           attribute.attributeName().name.toLowerCase().eq("eye color"),
           attribute.attributeValue.toLowerCase().eq("blue"))
     .exists()
```

In addition to `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` you can also use Querydsl queries via Spring Data like this

```
public class CustomerRepositoryImpl
 extends QuerydslRepositorySupport
 implements CustomerRepositoryCustom {

    public Iterable<Customer> findAllLongtermCustomersWithBirthday() {
        QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
        return from(customer)
           .where(hasBirthday().and(isLongTermCustomer()))
           .list(customer);
    }
}
```

Example taken from here https://blog.42.nl/articles/spring-data-jpa-with-querydsl-repositories-made-easy/

Comment: yep, I understand that.  I'm trying to see if there is a way to do it with the QueryDslPredicateExecutor, which would mean I wouldn't have to provide any implementation and the caller of the repository could craft more interesting queries without me having to expose a new method through the api.  In any case, thanks for the answer and the link.

Comment: Great update, thank you, upvoted.  I was aware of the any, but don't see how to join through the AttributeValue into the AttributeName and match them up.  I have updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Timo, I very much appreciate your time and effort on this. I understand that I will not be able to do what I wish using just the QueryDslPredicateExecutor and the spring-data-jpa module. A little code never hurt, I just wanted to see what the limits of the interface-only approach is.

Comment: new JPASubQuery()...exists() is a Predicate, so it's compatible with QueryDslPredicateExecutor.

Comment: I know this is old but is the paging restriction still applying? I'm usying the any() Method on my List Property and it seems to work except for pagining

Answer (score 9):

In order to perform more complex queries I've created my custom `QueryDslRepository` with support of JPQL queries and spring data JPA pagination.

Interface:

```
public interface QueryDslRepository<T> {

    Page<T> findAll(JPQLQuery<T> jpqlQuery, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Implementation:

```
@Repository
public class QueryDslRepositoryImpl<T> implements QueryDslRepository<T> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Page<T> findAll(JPQLQuery jpqlQuery, Pageable pageable) {
        Assert.notNull(jpqlQuery, "JPQLQuery must not be null!");
        Assert.notNull(pageable, "Pageable must not be null!");

        Querydsl querydsl = new Querydsl(entityManager, new PathBuilderFactory()
                                         .create(jpqlQuery.getType()));

        JPQLQuery<T> countQuery = ((AbstractJPAQuery) jpqlQuery).clone(entityManager);
        AbstractJPAQuery query = (AbstractJPAQuery) querydsl.applyPagination(pageable, jpqlQuery);
        return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(
                  // Clone query in order to provide entity manager instance.
                  query.clone(entityManager).fetch(), 
                  pageable, 
                  countQuery::fetchCount);
    }

}
```

Example of use:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>, QueryDslRepository<Customer>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Customer> {

}
```

Actual repository invocation:

```
 BooleanBuilder predicates = new BooleanBuilder();
 predicates = predicates.and(QCustomer.customer.active.eq(true));

 JPQLQuery<Customer> q = new JPAQuery<Customer>()
            .select(QCustomer.customer)
            // You can use .join() method here.
            .where(predicates);

 Page<Customer> result = customerRepository.findAll(q, Pageable.unpaged());
```

Comment: Hi I was hoping this would be my dream quick fix, but I have used it more or less per your example and I get the following error: `org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property id found for type Void!` in QueryDslRepositoryImpl.java:31 (the 'applyPagination' line) - I am trying to sort by "id"